Nginx, исполнить блок location при условии что запрос не на файл
location / {

}

Как верно прописать вместо слеша, условие. Что запрос пользователя не ведет на файл?
И наоборот, на тот случай когда url ведет на файл. Не ориентируясь на расширение файла, к примеру на точку в url или если есть вариант лучше то вообще супер будет...

Что означает «ведет на файл»?

К тому же про try_files вы уже в курсе

Я бы не хотел лишний раз нагружать сервер регулярными выражениями, тогда когда запрос пользователя идет на статичный файл.

Вам где-то в соседних вопросах уже писали что переживания о регулярных выражениях это чушь, но в любом случае try_files не имеет никакого отношения к регулярным выражениям

/, что за место слеша необходимо прописать чтобы подблоки не исполнялись, когда запрос идет на статичный файл?

Ничего, потому что проверка существования файла идёт внутри подблока, а не наоборот

Хотя в общем-то try_files способен работать вообще без блока location напрямую в блоке server

Производительность nginx это примерно последнее о чём надо волноваться если у вас не какой-то абсолютно безумный конфиг.
